# liquibase environment scripts

Tags: oracle, liquibase

I have just discovered Liquibase and I'm currently working on trying to automate my Oracle database releases.

I am trying to find out more about how I can use perform token replacement for my SQL scripts that may vary depending on my environment I run Liquibase on.

Specifically, does Liquibase support the concept of environment-based SQL scripts? I.e I may have certain custom SQL scripts which may differ slightly for Test, Regression and Live. So that when executing my Liquibase release to Regression, only those Regression specific changesets are executed, perhaps with a Regression parameter.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Liquibase uses 'labels' and 'contexts' to control which changesets are applied in different environments. This blog post describes them in more detail:

http://blog.liquibase.org/2014/11/contexts-vs-labels.html

Liquibase also supports properties in changelogs that can be set in various ways - this page of the docs shows the details:

http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changelog_parameters.html

Here is a snippet of that documentation:

> Liquibase allows dynamic substitution of parameters in a changelog.
>   The parameters to replace are described using the ${} syntax.
>
> **Configuring parameter values**
>
> Parameter values are looked up in the following order:
>
> - Passed as a parameter to your Liquibase runner (see Ant, command_line,
>     etc. documentation for how to pass them)
> - As a JVM system property
> - In the parameters block (<property> Tag) of the DatabaseChangeLog file
>     itself.

Comment: ah great! just had a quick look. I was specifically after token replacement, i.e. for my

Comment: Added some details on the property substitution feature.

Comment: Sorry I closed the laptop mid sentence in my last comment and it got posted. Thank you for the update to your original post. I was going to add that I am using sql formatted changelogs. I may have a requirement to "find and replace" values in my sql formatted changelogs depending on my environment. However, I guess dynamic substitution only supports XML based changelogs? Is my understanding correct? If so, how can I achieve dynamic substitution for sql formatted changelogs? Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, the features in SQL formatted changelogs are much more limited. Parsing cross platform SQL is a non-trivial exercise, and it has not been attempted in Liquibase yet. I recommend against using it if at all possible. If your DBAs are picky and want to see the SQL, it is better to use the XML format and generate the SQL (use the updateSQL command) to show them what would be run rather than try to use SQL formatted changelogs.